# Different data types in swift 3

Tags: swift

I understand different data types in programming and i understand that when we say var name = "John" , that means name is a variable of type string and holds the value "John", what i am struggling with is when we specify the type of the variable as a class like so:

```
    Class MyClass {
         //methods and properties
    }
   var class : MyClass
```

what is the value that the variable "class" is holding or can hold in the above line of code?!!

Comment: [Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html) in the Swift Language Reference would be a good place to start.

Comment: I have read a lot about classes and structures but still can't understand what "Value" the variable holds when it is of the class type, when the variable is an Int type then its value will be a number, when it is a String type then its value will be a string, when the variable is a class type its value will be ???????

Comment: Have a look at the "Classes Are Reference Types" section. The variable can hold a reference to a MyClass instance.

Comment: Although prior to being initialised, variables (regardless of type) don't hold any meaningful value, and the compiler will prevent you from accessing them until initialised.

Comment: what is the variable below exactly doing and what value does it hold?

Comment: let sendingVC:SDViewController = segue.destination as! SDViewController
    sendingVC.delegate = self